# How to scrape number of product sold using rvest in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rcurl

I want to scrape the number of product sold using Rvest from a marketplace webpage.

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwmGc.png)

I used this code, but it returned no value.

```
library(rvest)

doc <- read_html("https://www.tokopedia.com/berasprimasari/beras-bunga-25kg")

sold <- html_nodes(doc, ".rvm-product-info--item_value.mt-5.item-sold-count") %>%
    html_text()

sold

------------
RESULT:
[1] "     "

EXPECTED:
[1] " 378 "
```

How can I adjust my code to extract that number?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the issue is that the page is using AJAX to render that number, so you can't scrape it the conventional way. I'm not sure what works as an alternative, though. Maybe try poking around for solutions to that particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is retrieved dynamically from a product stats endpoint you can find in network tab. You could string split or simply regex out part giving number sold. You need to pass the product id which you can grab from a request to the original url.

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
library(httr)

get_product_id <- function(url){
  headers = c('User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0')
  s <- read_html(httr::GET(url, httr::add_headers(.headers=headers)))%>%html_text()
  id <- str_match_all(s,'product_id\\s+=\\s+(\\d+);')[[1]][,2]
  return(id)
}

url = 'https://www.tokopedia.com/berasprimasari/beras-bunga-25kg'
p <- read_html(paste0('https://js.tokopedia.com/productstats/check?pid=',get_product_id(url),'&callback=show_product_stats&_='))%>% 
     html_text()
number_sold <- str_match_all(p,'item_sold\":(\\d+)')[[1]][,2]
```

Comment: Is there any function, given the original url, to extract the pid=303286696?

Comment: I'm thinking of doing `getURL("https://www.tokopedia.com/berasprimasari/beras-bunga-25kg")` using `rcurl` first. But I don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: I added an helper function for you.